# Interfacing a wxPython GUI with Python Scripts

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxpython to build a GUI.
I have two questions:
1.How Can I get values from textfield in the interface? 
2.Can I run a python script through my interface(for examlpe when clicking on a button) and How to do it ?

Another question: after the execution of the script, which is supposed to return a result (a string) , how can I get the result from script and display it in my interface? Thanks.

PS: The values  in question 1 are arguments for the Python script in question 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If by textfiled you mean a wx.TextCtrl you get the value from it by calling its GetValue method.
2. You bind an event handler to the buttons event wx.EVT_BUTTON, in the handler you get the values from the TextCtrl and then call you functions/methods using them.

See the wxpython demo (available from wxpython site downloads) for examples of the above and a whole lot more

Comment: yes @Yoriz I mean a wx.TextControl, thank you for answering my question

Comment: @farfalla If you got the answer to your question then please select it as an answer. This helps other users to know that this question has been solved.